# How do I disable horizontal scrolling on smartphones? (HTML Webview)

Tags: html, css, webview

I'm working with a webview this time. I've got a strange behaviour here.

The overflow-x is set to hidden, and works just fine on browsers. But when it comes to any mobile device, it doesn't respect the overflow at all.

http://www2.madeinweb.com.br/jobs/adc/prototype/html/

This is the URL of it. If you try to open the menu, it will work as intended. But I can scroll the content I placed left. That doesn't happen on browsers.

I know I can fully disable scrolling with jQuery, but I can't find a proper way to disable just horizontal scrolling.

Any tips over it?

Comment: You could set the content to the width of the page?

Comment: Its all set up to 100%. I cant set a fixed width, this layout ranges a lot of viewports

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to tweak it out with touchmove. thanks no one for the answer